# PHP: What is the reason for the change in a timestamp after being converted to a date using the date function and back again?

Tags: php, date

I am getting an input in milliseconds. E.G: `$timestamp = 1479844722190;`

I convert that timestamp using `$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $timestamp / 1000);`

I convert back to a timestamp using `strtotime($date);`

My result is 1479801522

The same thing happens when using `gmdate()`.

The actual code:

date():

```
    $timestamp = get_timestamp(); // 1479847575022
    $date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $timestamp / 1000); // 2016-11-22 08:46:15
    strtotime($date); // 1479804375
```

gmdate():

```
    $timestamp = get_timestamp(); // 1479847661576
    $date = gmdate('Y-m-d h:i:s', $timestamp / 1000); // 2016-11-22 08:47:41
    strtotime($date); // 1479804461
```

Could someone tell my why this happens, and whether there is a way to do this without creating a time-machine like this?

UPDATE:

Putting `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')` beforehand gives the following results:

```
timestamp: 1479848532028
date: 2016-11-22 09:02:12
reverted: 1479805332

timestamp: 1479848622222
date: 2016-11-22 09:03:42
reverted: 1479805422
```

Comment: timezonesssssss

Comment: Try `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')` before your code to see if the problem goes away to confirm the problem is timezones.  Unix timestamps should always be in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

After a sleeping on it, I found the answer.

`gmdate('Y-m-d h:i:s', $timestamp / 1000);`

should really be:

`gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp / 1000);`